# Which framework exist for ruby to use only for services SOA with MySQL that accept models (like the M in MVC)? no need for V and C

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, frameworks, soa

I need to build a simple app in a browser:
The interface will be build by javascript and the data will be get/set to the server by the browser

Comment: Your javascript interface is the V.

Comment: that's why I dont need to be included in the ruby framework*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORMs are not intrinsically linked to MVC frameworks, so feel free to just use ActiveRecord, DataMapper etc. for your app without using a full-fledged framework. If you look around a bit you'll find several blog posts on this topic, e.g.

http://dmathieu.com/en/ruby/ruby-use-active-record-without-rails

Answer (score 1):

Consider combining [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) and [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/). You might also find the [Github Services](https://github.com/github/github-services) interesting as an example app that uses Sinatra.

Comment: +1 for Sinatra, though it can be combined with ActiveRecord or DataMapper too.

Comment: I've a pref for Sequel, myself. But that's probably because I'm an SQL junkie. :-)